__subclasses__() and import
There are two files with a chain of commands and a dict that dynamically collects all non-abstract commands.
logic.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Command(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        ...

class Commands(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        import comm
        breakpoint()
        for cls in Command.__subclasses__():
            names = self.split_camel_case(cls.__name__)
            self[names] = cls

comm.py
from logic import Command

class TestCommand(Command):
    ...

Debugger output
> logic.py(28) __init__()
  -> for cls in Command.__subclasses__():

(Pdb) comm.TestCommand.__mro__
(<class 'comm.TestCommand'>, <class 'logic.Command'>, <class 'abc.ABC'>, <class 'object'>)

(Pdb) Command.__subclasses__()
[]

By the time the Commands.__init__() is called the base class Command is already defined. The module comm is imported and the subclass TestCommand is defined too. But the list returned by Command.__subclass__() is empty.
Tell me please, what am I missing?

Where, exactly, is Commands instantiated?  It's apparently at a point before comm.py has reached the point of defining its subclass.

This code is tested with python -i logic.py. So, I suppose, Commands is instantiated from logic (as __main__) module namespace. Also, note that I import comm inside Commands constructor

it might be something specific to ABC... if you make Command a regular class does it work?

@Anentropic, nope. I've also tried to import comm just between defining Command and Commands classes. Does not work too.

With the @Anentropic answer it has begun clear what question to ask. And I found that it had been already discussed here.
In few words, a __main__ module is always created by default and without Python import system. But if you import an entry point file from another module, the interpreter will process this file for the second time with its import system. This results with a second module object referring to the same entry point file.
This is easy to find. For my code from question post:
$ python -i logic.py
>>> from sys import modules
>>> import comm
>>> 
>>> modules['__main__'].__loader__.path
'...\\tests\\prototypes\\logic.py'
>>> 
>>> modules['logic'].__loader__.path
'...\\tests\\prototypes\\logic.py'


Speaking about the problem with referring to the Command class. The first way is to move that class to another file, as @Anentropic suggested.
However, I would like to keep my Command abstract base class alongside with the other logic classes in one file. Fortunately, in my case there is the second simple way to refer the desired Command class.
logic.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Command(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        ...

class Commands(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        import comm
        print(f'{Command.__subclasses__() = }')
        print(f'{comm.Command.__subclasses__() = }')

comm.py
from logic import Command

class TestCommand(Command):
    ...

$ python logic.py
Command.__subclasses__() = []
comm.Command.__subclasses__() = [<class 'comm.TestCommand'>]

As you can see, the second reference is exactly the one you need to get all Command subclasses.

By the way, there is also the third way. I have used it when had been stuck with an import issue. The idea is that the file comm.py should contain only subclasses of Command abstract base class. As long as you keep it like that, you can use the inspect module instruments.
logic.py
from inspect import getmembers, isclass

class Commands(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        import comm
        print(getmembers(comm, isclass))

comm.py
import logic

class TestCommand(logic.Command):
    ...

$ python logic.py
[('TestCommand', <class 'comm.TestCommand'>)]


I think the problem is that, confusingly, the Command class object you see from inside Commands.__init__ is not the same one that TestCommand inherits from.
On one level, yes they are the same, but to the Python import system they are different.
Try this code and see what happens:
logic.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Command(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        ...

class Commands(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        import comm
        print(Command.__module__)
        print(Command.__subclasses__())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Commands()

comm.py
from logic import Command

class TestCommand(Command):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Command.__module__)
    print(Command.__subclasses__())

$ python comm.py
logic
[<class '__main__.TestCommand'>]

$ python logic.py
__main__
[]

Note how the two Command class references have a different __module__ value.
Commands.__init__ has a reference to the Command class that was defined before the module it belongs to had been fully defined.
We can fix this by moving the logic to a third file:
base.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Command(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        ...

comm.py
from base import Command

class TestCommand(Command):
    ...

logic.py
from base import Command
import comm

class Commands(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        print(Command.__module__)
        print(Command.__subclasses__())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Commands()

Now when we run it we get the desired result:
$ python logic.py
base
[<class 'comm.TestCommand'>]

...because logic.py and comm.py are both referring to the same Command class, imported from the same location.

Thank you for showing the difference of Command references! I'll try to dig in that mechanics.
